# Return Max and min not working right

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a file :

```
operation1,83123
operation2,72321
operation3,13288
operation2,12312
operation1,45455
operation2,42543
operation5,344
operation4,61321
operation3,71724
operation5,54546
operation1,12298
operation6,38999
operation3,76798
operation4,53983
```

My Code;

```
f = open('ops.log', 'r')   
data = f.readlines()
print max(data), min(data)
```

operation6,38999
operation1,12298

why is it not able to return right value

Comment: 1) what is your expected output? 2) The entire line is being read, are you expecting the `min` and `max` of the integers to the right of the comma?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the values after the comma, you can do something like this:

```
with open('ops.log', 'r') as log_fh:
    data = [int(line.split(',')[1]) for line in log_fh.readlines()]
    print max(data), min(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = [int(i.split(",")[1]) for i in infile.readlines()]   #Split str by comma and get 1st index

print(max(data))
print(min(data))
```

**Output:**

```
83123
344
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the lines with min and max per second column, use this:

```
with open('ops.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = sorted(f.read().split('\n'), key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[1]))
    minimum, maximum = lines[0], lines[-1]
    print minimum, maximum
#operation5,344 operation1,83123
```